# Syntax of hamcrest matchers

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, junit, hamcrest

In one of our projects I stumbled upon the following line of code (it uses hamcrest matchers 1.3):

```
assertThat(someReport.getSomeException(), Matchers.<SomeException>notNullValue())
```

Two questions:

1. Would somebody please explain this syntax to me? I've never seen the use of < and > in that context.
2. Eclipse highlights the latter part of that line as en error: `The method notNullValue() of type Matchers is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <SomeException>`. However, using maven on the commandline the project builds without problems. So why is there an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This is proper syntax for specifying the generic parameter when calling a static method. If you have the following method...

   public  T myMethod();

You could call it as `MyClass.<String>myMethod()`. In many cases type inference allow for not including the `<>`. For example the work work for the above: `String myVal = MyClass.myMethod()`.

1. The javadoc for `Matchers` has the following signature for `notNullValue`

   public static Matcher notNullValue()

Notice that the is no generic variable `<T>` therefore it is not proper to specify one. If it is compiling, I assume it is because the compiler is ignoring it.